# Can I use Postgres transactions only for write queries and use read queries without transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What happens if I use transactions for write operations but don't use those for read operations?
My use case:

1. get some data1 from db (without transaction)
2. create some data2 using data1 (with transaction)
3. get some data3 from db (without transaction)
4. create some data4 using data2 and data3 (with transaction)
5. If no error commit otherwise rollback.

Is it something wrong that I am not using transaction for the 2 read queries?

Comment: The search term is `dirty reads`, or `read committed`

Comment: @Radu you might be referring to [Postgres Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)

Comment: You can't really do something "without a transaction". If you don't explicitly create one, then each statement you run will automatically run in its own transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're going to query the database for the same rows that you just inserted using a transaction, but haven't committed the transaction yet, then you should read from the database using the transaction.
Eg. You create a user, then you need to create an external account for this user, and the method that creates that external account reads the user from the database and does not get it as a parameter. You can either modify the create external account method so it gets the user as a parameter and then pass to it the just created user, either you can keep the method like it is, but you have to make sure you pass the transaction to it. Otherwise, if the transaction is not committed and is not passed to the read query, the created user won't be found.
Ideally you should avoid this thing by passing the input data to the create external account too, so you don't need to read the user from db, but if for some reason this is not possible, then make sure you read from the db using the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit/Add/Delete Records

A Transaction is used when you want to ensure that a bunch of row edit/add/delete queries are committed together to the db. In other wards, you want to ensure that all sql commands in that bunch runs successfully or don't commit any of the commands. E.g. you are saving a new record for a users table and a users address table together, but you might not want to write to the users table if the address table record fails for some reason. In this case you would use a transaction for both commands.

#### Read Records

If you understand the above, you know you don't need transactions for read sql commands.

**BUT....** if you want to read your changes before committing your edit/add/delete then you should read within the transaction.

`Was the answer helpful? Consider marking the answer tick and upvoting. Thanks`

Comment: I understand I don't really need transactions if I only use read queries.
But I think I read somewhere that if you use write queries and also read queries, you should use the read query with transaction too. But can't really remember the reason. that's why I am asking.

Comment: You don't... for the above reason. It is not making any changes to the db and is not related to the purpose of using Transactions

Comment: What if I am reading from a table that I just added data to? If the transaction is not commited and I am reading without a transaction from the table where the data is supposed to be updated when commiting the transaction?

Comment: I know I can return the data that I just wrote to the db so don't need to make an aditional read query, but just theoritcally, what happens if I am reading from a table that has been updated, but the transaction was not commited?

Comment: You should read before or after the transaction to ensure transaction success or failure. Reading the record from the db, before a transaction is committed would give what was in the db before the transaction was committed. Old data!

Comment: @Radu you might have read about [Postgres Transaction Isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)

Answer (score 1):

If that sequence is fine or not depends on your requirements. With your current procedure, the following could happen:

- if you encounter an error before step 2 finishes, nothing has changed
- if you encounter an error before step 5 finishes, you have only data2, but not data4
- if no error happens before step 5 has completed, you have data2 and data4

If that is fine for you, there is no problem with what you are doing.